# get-distro-upgrade.py Failed to execute process

Tags: gnome, package-management

Every time I open the GNOME package updater on Ubuntu 18.04 (Cosmic), I receive the following message:

```
Spawn of helper '/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py' failed: failed to spawn /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py: Failed to execute child process “/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py” (No such file or directory)
```

The question is how can I fix this issue using the terminal? What commands or methods should be used? I appreciate any advice and assistance given. I am a newbie to the Linux operating system. I made the transition from Windows based off my decision to pursue becoming a full stack developer. I'm also learning game development. So far I have been using the Linux distribution, Ubuntu 18.04 Cosmic. Also, here goes a screenshot to get a better look up close and personal.

Desktop GNOME GUI Screenshot Given Below.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu at all?   You've mixed in a couple of places two releases of Ubuntu where a real Ubuntu machine will list release and a matching code-name.   Are you using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ? or cosmic?  18.04 is bionic, 18.10 is cosmic.  I don't know what command gave you 18.04 cosmic; but please elaborate as it shows a very screwed up system (ie. if you've introduced cosmic sources into your bionic system you'll be reaching EOL soon; so I suggest you check question or `ubuntu-support-status`)

Comment: Today I had the same issue. Using 18.04 LTS here, whatever name it has (Bionic BTW)...